# python pandas: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Could you please advise how the following lines 
should be re-written based on 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

1. `df.drop('PACKETS', axis=1, inplace=True)`

produces

```
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df.drop('PACKETS', axis=1, inplace=True)
/home/app/ip-spotlight/code/app/ipacc/plugin/ix.py:74: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

2. `df.replace(numpy.nan, "", inplace=True)`

produces

```
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df.replace(numpy.nan, "", inplace=True)
/home/app/ip-spotlight/code/app/ipacc/plugin/ix.py:68: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

On the other hand, the following is an example of how it was re-written based on the above principle

```
df.loc[:, ('SRC_PREFIX')]   = df[ ['SRC_NET', 'SRC_MASK'] ].apply(lambda x: "/".join(x), axis=1)
```

But i am unable to figure out how to re-write the cases 1 and 2 ?

**EDIT**: the code so far it looks like this (`df` is the dataframe of interest). So initially the is some kind of casting:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data['payload'], columns=sorted(data['header'], key=data['header'].get))
        df = df.astype({
            'SRC_AS'                : "object",
            'DST_AS'                : "object",
            'COMMS'                 : "object",
            'SRC_COMMS'             : "object",
            'AS_PATH'               : "object",
            'SRC_AS_PATH'           : "object",
            'PREF'                  : "object",
            'SRC_PREF'              : "object",
            'MED'                   : "object",
            'SRC_MED'               : "object",
            'PEER_SRC_AS'           : "object",
            'PEER_DST_AS'           : "object",
            'PEER_SRC_IP'           : "object",
            'PEER_DST_IP'           : "object",
            'IN_IFACE'              : "object",
            'OUT_IFACE'             : "object",
            'SRC_NET'               : "object",
            'DST_NET'               : "object",
            'SRC_MASK'              : "object",
            'DST_MASK'              : "object",
            'PROTOCOL'              : "object",
            'TOS'                   : "object",
            'SAMPLING_RATE'         : "uint64",
            'EXPORT_PROTO_VERSION'  : "object",
            'PACKETS'               : "object",
            'BYTES'                 : "uint64",
        })
```

Then the `calculate` function of a module is called:

```
mod.calculate(data['identifier'], data['timestamp'], df)
```

And the `calculate` function is defined like this:

```
def calculate(identifier, timestamp, df):
    try:
        #   Filter based on AORTA IX.
        lut_ipaddr = lookup_ipaddr()
        df = df[ (df.PEER_SRC_IP.isin( lut_ipaddr )) ]
        if df.shape[0] > 0:
            logger.info('analyzing message `{}`'.format(identifier))
            #   Preparing for input.
            df.replace("", numpy.nan, inplace=True)
            #   Data wrangling. Calculate traffic rate. Reduce.
            df.loc[:, ('BPS')]          = 8*df['BYTES']*df['SAMPLING_RATE']/300
            df.drop(columns=['SAMPLING_RATE', 'EXPORT_PROTO_VERSION', 'PACKETS', 'BYTES'], inplace=True)
            #   Data wrangling. Formulate prefixes using CIDR notation. Reduce.
            df.loc[:, ('SRC_PREFIX')]   = df[ ['SRC_NET', 'SRC_MASK'] ].apply(lambda x: "/".join(x), axis=1)
            df.loc[:, ('DST_PREFIX')]   = df[ ['DST_NET', 'DST_MASK'] ].apply(lambda x: "/".join(x), axis=1)
            df.drop(columns=['SRC_NET', 'SRC_MASK', 'DST_NET' ,'DST_MASK'], inplace=True)
            #   Populate using lookup tables.
            df.loc[:, ('NETELEMENT')]   = df['PEER_SRC_IP'].apply(lookup_netelement)
            df.loc[:, ('IN_IFNAME')]    = df.apply(lambda x: lookup_iface(x['NETELEMENT'], x['IN_IFACE']), axis=1)
            df.loc[:, ('OUT_IFNAME')]   = df.apply(lambda x: lookup_iface(x['NETELEMENT'], x['OUT_IFACE']), axis=1)
            # df.loc[:, ('SRC_ASNAME')]   = df.apply(lambda x: lookup_asn(x['SRC_AS']), axis=1)
            #   Add a timestamp.
            df.loc[:, ('METERED_ON')]   = arrow.get(timestamp, "YYYYMMDDHHmm").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
            #   Preparing for input.
            df.replace(numpy.nan, "", inplace=True)
            #   Finalize !
            return identifier, timestamp, df.to_dict(orient="records")
        else:
            logger.info('going through message `{}` no IX bgp/netflow data were found'.format(identifier))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('processing message `{}` at `{}` caused `{}`'.format(identifier,timestamp,repr(e)), exc_info=True)
    return identifier, timestamp, None
```

Comment: Probably this can help you: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Comment: @Georgy thanks but if i am not mistaken the case with `drop` and `replace` that have no assignment are not covered.

Comment: How do you define df? If df is a slice of another dataframe, the you can use `copy` to stop this warning. `df = df_full.loc[somefilters].copy()`

Comment: @ScottBoston `drop` and `replace` need a label

Comment: @iamsterdam I don't understand.  need a label?

Comment: @ScottBoston i assume that you are suggesting sth like that `df.loc[:, ('PACKETS')].drop()` maybe ?

Comment: @iamsterdam No... I am suggesting that when you first create df.  How do you do it?  If df is created from a slice of a bigger dataframe, then you are trying to do assignments in this slice, you have a change of getting this error.  To prevent this error.  Create df with .copy.  Then try your replace and drop statements as is.

Comment: @ScottBoston ah no, the dataframe is created from a .csv file

Comment: @iamsterdam Have you managed to resolve the issue? If you read the dataframe from csv and right after that you drop the column, then you shouldn't get the warning. Can you provide all the code up to the moment where you are dropping the column?

Comment: thanks @Georgy. I edited the original post above to include this info. unfortunately not get, i didn't manage to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I don't really know what is going on under the hood of pandas. But still, I've tried to come up with some minimal examples to show you where the problem can be and what you can do about it.
First, creating dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[0, 1, 2],
                       y=[0, 0, 5]))
```

Then, as you pass your dataframe to a function, I will do the same but for 2 almost identical functions:

```
def func(dfx):
    # Analog of your df = df[df.PEER_SRC_IP.isin(lut_ipaddr)]
    dfx = dfx[dfx['x'] > 1.5]
    # Analog of your df.replace("", numpy.nan, inplace=True)
    dfx.replace(5, np.nan, inplace=True)
def func_with_copy(dfx):
    dfx = dfx[dfx['x'] > 1.5].copy()  # explicitly making a copy
    dfx.replace(5, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Now let's call them for initial df:

```
func_with_copy(df)
print(df)
```

gives

```
   x  y
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  2  5
```

and no warning. And calling this:

```
func(df)
print(df)
```

gives the same output:

```
   x  y
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  2  5
```

but with the warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:6: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

So this looks like a 'false positive'. Here is a good comment on false positives: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20644369/7851470)

Strange thing here is that if you do exactly the same manipulations with your dataframe but without passing it to a function, then you won't see this warning. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

My advice is to use `.copy()`

Comment: indeed the warning pops up after passing the dataframe to a function